# c# datagridview sum cells value

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I want to sum cells in DataGridView and display the result in a MessageBox.

I have two DataGridViews. The first DataGridView gets data from database. The second DataGridView gets values after I select row from first DataGridView.

This is my code

```
   private void actionStatistics_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < productsDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            total += int.Parse(productsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Total quantity: " + total);
    }
```

I get error in this line:

```
     total += int.Parse(productsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
```

Error is:

```
     An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in task3.exe. 
     Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can someone help me find a solution?

Comment: I think the issue is that Cell[6] does not have any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for a null value before adding:

```
total += int.Parse(productsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6]?.Value?.ToString());
```

Or the old way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < productsDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
             if(productsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6] !=null && productsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value != null)
             {
                total +=     int.Parse(productsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The cell [i,6] is null, use a condition to check.
2. It is a better practice to check also if the value is a number, because if it is not a number you will get an exception (when using `Parse()` and not `TryParse()`).
   here is an example how to do it with [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

   ```
       private void actionStatistics_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           int total = 0;

           for (int i = 0; i < productsDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
           {
               if (productsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6] != null && (productsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString().IsNumeric()))
               {
                   total += int.Parse(productsDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
               }
           }

           MessageBox.Show("Total quantity: " + total);
       }

   }
   public static class ExtensionMethods
   {
       public static bool IsNumeric(this string s)
       {
           float output;
           return float.TryParse(s, out output);
       }
   }
   ```